# How to shown all the category on home page in magento2

Tags: magento2, category, collection

```
public function getShopCategories()
{
    $objectManagerr = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryFactory = $objectManagerr->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

    $categories = $categoryFactory->create()
                                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                  ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories

    return $categories;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method to get category collection in Magento 2:

```
protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;
protected $_categoryHelper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true)
{
    $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');        

    // select only active categories
    if ($isActive) {
        $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
    }   

    return $collection;
}

public function getStoreCategories()
{
    return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories();
}
```

Or refer this blog: [Magento 2 Frontend: How to call category collection on home page](https://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-frontend-how-to-call-category-collection-on-home-page)